# Download files without knowing the extensions

Tags: asp.net, excel, ssms

I had an excel file which had for each row a column named id with a link value that open up other files the id doesn't have .(extension) on it.

The problem is that I imported the excel file on SQL Server Management, and the links is now strings without extension i want it to be displayed as a link in my grid view on asp.net page to open up the named file...

To mention there is at least 700 rows on the database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you still have the original data with extensions?

Comment: Please post some code what you have tried so far?

Comment: the excel file you mean ? if yess then yeah i still have it